# Regex preg_replace how to filter string between brackets

Tags: regex

I have a variable

```
$desc = "[vc_row][vc_column][vc_basic_grid post_type="page" max_items="99"]more text I dont want to cut"
```

and I need to filter everything except "**more text I dont want to cut**".

I was trying something like:

```
$desc = preg_replace('/\[\/?=vc/\.*?\]/','', $desc);
```

Comment: What did you get from this?

Comment: nvm I have just solved it with: $desc = preg_replace('/\[\/?vc.*?\]/','', $desc);

Comment: congratulations!!!!